# What are the benefits of using Kaktovik numerals?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, real-numbers

I read the article ["*A Number System Invented by Inuit Schoolchildren Will Make Its Silicon Valley Debut*"](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-number-system-invented-by-inuit-schoolchildren-will-make-its-silicon-valley-debut/).

The article claims that the system is strikingly visual when used for arithmetic.

My question, are there any computational advantages to such a representation?

Can it make doing numerical calculations more efficient, are the number bases used more beneficial in other contexts or use cases, are there advantages to teaching it, etc.?

Comment: This might be better suited at Math Educators SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is difficult to answer a question like this objectively—any discussion regarding advantages or benefits of any representation of knowledge requires a nuanced discussion of *what* is considered an advantage and to *whom* they are advantages. Is it an advantage if the numeral system is easier to do "hand-calculations" with but is more computationally inefficient? Is it an advantage if it is more visually intuitive for representing numbers below 100 than the Arabic numerals, but less if not? (You get the point, I hope.)

Ultimately, the Kaktovik numerals appear to be a way to translate Iñupiaq word-conceptions of numbers into a numeral system that is much more intuitive in that language than the Arabic numerals. The stroke-based system, similar to the Roman numerals, makes developing a visual intuition for arithmetic operations on numbers smaller than 20, or close to 20, easier* than with their Arabic counterparts (**it will depend on what you find more intuitive, of course*). I do not think that the numerals are more efficient for purely computation purposes, nor do I think there is any ground-shattering breakthrough in the conceptualization of numbers via the development of this system.

What I subjectively find very meaningful about the development of this numeral system, and the push to represent such numbers in Unicode, is more humanistic and concrete; it is allowing younger members of Iñupiat communities to learn arithmetic in a more efficient way by helping them describe numbers in a format that is more cohesive with their primary language, and allowing them to transfer those mathematical skills into computers (where everyone does most of their math nowadays) more efficiently. And it is also a beautiful (*subjective!*) mathematical construction in the sense that it is a number representation that appears to have been largely motivated, and developed by, schoolchildren and their needs.

So, should we all switch to using and/or teaching Kaktovik numerals instead of Arabic ones? Probably not. But, in my opinion, they're still a wonderfully creative and materially beneficial conceptualization of numbers!